# Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI Migration Tool Error

Tags: c#, .net, maui

When I CD to my path and run "upgrade-assistant upgrade *My sln here*", it runs the assistant and I choose 1 (I use interactive mode as its easier to see errors) and it acts like it will convert but then it errors out with "unexpected error applying step System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "Path to android csproj" is denied".

I have tried running PowerShell as administrator and normal multiple times with the same outcome. Any suggestions? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Maybe disable "User Account Dontrol"? (Not sure if that will do any better than running as Administrator.)